# Hiding pointer member implementation from header file

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am using a [library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) - nlohmann/json and want to have a member that points to `json` for internal usage.

I'd like to avoid pulling the whole library as a compile time dependency so I considered using a pointer to a forward declared struct

in the header

```
struct my_json; // forward declare 

std::unique_ptr<my_json> memberJson;
```

in the cpp:

```
struct my_json : public nlohmann::json {};
```

But the issue is that when I try to use it inside the class I get either

```
error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'nlohmann::json *' to 'my_json *'
```

When trying to assign the address of a result of `reference operator[](const typename object_t::key_type& key)` back to `my_json *`

or

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'nlohmann::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::adl_serializer>' to 'my_json  &'
```

when trying to assign result of `reference operator[](const typename object_t::key_type& key)` to a `my_json &` directly

Is there an elegant solution to that ? (If I want to avoid `reinterpret_cast`ing the pointers)  is `static_cast`ing safe in this scenario ?

Comment: I suppose the `class my_json` and `struct my_json` is a typo?

Comment: With inheritance of the form `struct my_json : public nlohmann::json {};`, a `my_json *`  can be converted implicitly to a `nlohmann::json *`   (i.e. from derived to base).   The reverse (conversion from base to derived) is not valid.    Without knowing why you're trying to do the conversion in the wrong direction, it's not really possible to advise on a solution.

Comment: @ThomasCaissard - There is no real difference between the two in this case.  `class` and `struct` are the same thing, except that default access and default inheritance for a `struct` are `public`, and for for a `class` are `private`.

Comment: @Peter I have a member collection that stores pointers to `my_json *` as well, also some internal functions expect to communicate between themselves with `my_json *` (e.g. return values or parameters). The declarations must be in the header so I'm "stuck" with defining it as `my_json *` and not the real type.
It compiled if I `static_cast<my_json*>` , is that well defined (assuming that the inheritance is exactly that and doesn't introduce anything)

Comment: static_cast will work and even adjust the pointer if needed (e.g. for multiple inheritance). However, if your pointer doesn't point to an object of dynamic type my_json (or a type derived from it) you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: What keeps you from providing an (empty) conversion constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you forward declare `nlohmann::json`?

```
namespace nlohmann { class json; }
```

Edit: I have used `json_fwd.hpp`.(https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/master/include/nlohmann/json_fwd.hpp)

Header:

```
#pragma once
#include "json_fwd.hpp"
#include <memory>

class A {
    std::unique_ptr<nlohmann::json> ptr;

    public:
        A();
        ~A();
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "json.hpp"

A::A() :
    ptr(std::make_unique<nlohmann::json>()) {

    (*ptr)["Hallo"] = 2;
}

A::~A() = default;
```

Comment: IIRC `nlohmann::json` is actually a typedef for an instance of a template with a bunch of policies as arguments, so that wouldn't work. Which pains me greatly.

Comment: @Quentin Would that mean that you cannot forward declare it this way?

Comment: @Quentin is right, it won't compile when `nlohmann::json` is forward declared (see https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/314). My fault, I haven't tried before.

Comment: The custom deleter is overkill: just declare `~A();` in the header and define `A::~A() = default;` in the .cpp file and the default deleter will work :) -- In any case, `json_fwd.h` is definitely made for this purpose (hence the `_fwd` suffix), so good catch.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, I have adapted my answer.